# Detect emails in a text and surrond it with the <a> tag

Tags: java, regex, email, extract

greetings all
I have a text that may contains emails
and I want to detect any email occurrence and surround it with the `< a >` tag
ex:

```
my.email@mycompany.com
<a href="mailto:my.email@mycompany.com"> my.email@mycompany.com </a>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex from [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) you can do:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4})\\b",
                       "<a href=\"mailto:$1\"> $1 </a>");
```

[Ideone Link](http://www.ideone.com/JwYWG)

Comment: It should be noted that this expression will not pick up all valid e-mail addresses (e.g. `\@Joe\ Blogs@example.com`); whether you use it depends on how tolerant of errors you can be.