# Surround all email matches in a string with tags

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've been trying different functions to replace any `blahhhh@blahhh.blahhh` inside a `contentEditable` DIV without success. There's either problems with the regex or with the fact that `[String].replaceAll` isn't an existing prototype in Chrome so I need to use any `replaceAll` I find on the web.

What should be the cross-browser (Chrome/WebKit/Moz) algorithm to replace all emails inside a string with a custom pattern?

Comment: use a regex with the `g` modifier to replace all. i.e., `'string'.replace(/whatever/g)`

Comment: I've tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/HZXuD/ based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561464/detect-emails-in-a-text-and-surrond-it-with-the-a-tag

Comment: But it shows me an invalid group, a bit like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200157/javascript-regular-expression-exception-invalid-group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replaceAll` isn't a standard function, indeed, but a regex should work:

Something simple like this:

> [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}

Can already work pretty well:

```
var s = "sample@mail.com is a sample email address with an @, as is some.mail@some.government";
s.replace(/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,})/ig, '<tag>$1</tag>');
// "<tag>sample@mail.com</tag> is a sample email address with an @, as is <tag>some.mail@some.government</tag>";

# Match:
# (              --> Start group
# [A-Z0-9._%+-]+ --> one or more characters within the specified range,
# @              --> Followed by an `@`,
# [A-Z0-9.-]+    --> Followed by some more characters,
# \.             --> Followed by an dot,
# [A-Z]{2,}      --> followed by 2 or more letters,
# )              --> End group.
# ig             --> (i)gnore case, (g)lobal.
# In the replacement:
# $1             --> Content of the first pair of `()`
```

Comment: How can I extract the original email as a group in the replacement part? I'm not good at regex.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, _"extract the original"_? Do you want to use the original email in the replacement?

Comment: Exactly. Since mail@mail.com needs to become <tag>mail@mail.com</tag> Thanks for your tuto, btw.

Comment: Ah, like that. I'll edit the answer, just a second. --- Done.